# Include chat (HTML, js, css) in all pages of WordPress

Tags: widgets, javascript, html

I need to add a chat widget in HTML, css and js, on all WP website. I tried the following in local (functions.php) and it worked fine but just on homepage. Same code online and nothing shows up. Any advice? Thank you in advance :)

```
<?php
     function add_chat ( ) { 
     ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            SERVICE_PATTERN_CHAT_CONFIG = {
                appId: '',
                clientId: '',            /* no need to change this */
                apiUrl: '',
                tenantUrl: '',
                width: 300,
                chatPath: ''

            };
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/snippet.js"></script>
    <?php
        }

add_action ('wp_footer', 'add_chat' );?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to include your inline script at the bottom of your `snipper.js` file, and then enqueue it using `wp_enqueue_scripts()`:

```
function my_chat_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'chat-js', 'URL OF SNIPPER HERE', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_chat_script' );
```

This is the proper way to include scripts in your WordPress using `functions.php` file.

However, if you insist on adding them separately, you can use `wp_add_inline_script()`:

```
function chat_script() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-chat-script', 'SNIPPER URL HERE', array(), '1.0' );
   wp_add_inline_script( 'my-chat-script', 'SERVICE_PATTERN_CHAT_CONFIG = {appId: '0ef0636b4c36497b866322a096926049', clientId: 'WebChat',apiUrl: 'https://poc.3d2b.ccaas.becloudsolutions.com:9443/clientweb/api/v1',tenantUrl: '3d2b.com',width: 300,chatPath: ''};' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chat_script' );
```

This will output your snippet and inline script separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's much easier to read formatted code whenever it's indented 4 spaces or by clicking the `{}` button in the answer editor which will do the indentation for you.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yea sorry i have serious problem with this. My screen is not big enough so it's real exhausting to type a code, unless i type it elsewhere first. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your answer. Eventually, I managed to add the chat using `wp_register` and `wp_enqueue` like this:

```
function add_chat_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'chat', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/chat.js' , array(), true );
    wp_register_script( 'chat-snippet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/snippet.js', array('chat') );
    wp_enqueue_script  ('chat');
    wp_enqueue_script('chat-snippet');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_chat_scripts' );
```

And it worked. But now, the problem is the chat shows up only in homepage and nowhere else. How can I solve that? You can see the chat [here](http://becloudsolutions.com) (It's not working in chrome and firefox though)

I tride the `wp_register`, etc on local. Online there's still the inline script, but is working anyway.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please consider marking your own answer as accepted, if it worked for you.

Comment: Hi Jack, It didnt wokr. I still Can see It only in homepage

Comment: Hi do you mean that it doesn't work on other pages? or it's not outputted in header at all?

Comment: The chat is visible just in homepage. In all the other pages of websites it gives me an "HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI" error.